# django's user.get_absolute_url doesn't work in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i'm kind of new to Django and have a problem with get_absolute_url in Django built-in user object, using it in template.
I'm using Django 1.7.

so, this is in the models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('tests:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

in urls.py:

```
url(
    regex=r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)',
    view = views.profile,
    name='profile'
)
```

views.py:

```
def profile(req, pk):

user = get_object_or_404(models.User, pk=pk)
return render(req, 'accounts/profile.html', {'user': user})
```

and in template

```
<div class="container">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">{{ user.username }}</a>
    <a href="{% url 'tests:logout' %}">Log out</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'tests:login' %}">Log in</a>
    <a href="{% url 'tests:register' %}">Sign up</a>
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

In html href is empty. When I use {% url 'tests:profile' user.pk %} it works perfectly well, and on the profile page, when user object is not Django's built-in but taken from my view, get_absolute_url works. Calling get_absolute_url from objects in shell also works as it should.

In 1.7 release notes written: "Define a get_absolute_url() method on your own custom user object or use ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES if you want a URL for your user."

So my method should work or I misunderstand something?
How to make built-in user's get_absolute_url work as expected?

Comment: I don't understand where your `get_absolute_url` is actually defined. You say it's "in the models.py", but then you say this is Django's own User model, so how can you be defining it in a class you don't control? You do realize that this is a method, and has to live in the relevant class, right? Since this you are using the built-in model, you should be using the alternative, ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES, as the doc states.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, my bad, I subclassed django's User model and thought that django will somehow handle my methods. I'm now trying to use ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES as `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: "/profile/%s/" % u.pk,
}` in settings.py, but it doesn't seem to change something, should I do something else to make this work?   
**UPD** I updated to 1.7.1 and now everything works fine. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: @fed_tf: I've converted your solution in the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting OP's comment:

> I updated to 1.7.1 and now everything works fine.